# No data saved when inserting a record in DB in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a Ruby On Rails complete beginner and I am writing a small application and I am stuck when trying to add a new record to a table. My issue is that no data is sent to be saved.

The table structure is:

```
create_table "committees", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name",        limit: 50
t.text     "description"
t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
end
```

The code for "new" and "create" operations is:

```
def new
  @committee = Committee.new
end

def create
  @committee = Committee.new(committee_params)

  if @committee.save
    redirect_to(committees_path)
  else
    render("new")
  end
end

private

def committee_params
  params.require(:name).permit(:description)
end
```

And the view is:

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", committees_path, :class => "back-link") %>

<div>
    <h2>Create Committee</h2>
    <%= form_for(@committee) do |f| %>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td><%= f.text_field(:description) %></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div>
            <%= f.submit("Create Committee") %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I know that no data is sent to be saved because I changed

```
params.require(:name).permit(:description)
```

to

```
params.permit(:name, :description)
```

And a blank record was inserted. Both fields are blank.

I will very much appreciate your comments to help solve my issue.

Respectfully,
Jorge Maldonado

Answer (score 4):

You should have

```
def committee_params
  params.require(:committee).permit(:name, :description)  
end
```

What this does is tell rails that you will be accepting a `committee` object in the params hash, and that you explicitly will only be accepting the `name` and `description` fields for that committee. This is called white listing your parameters.

You can learn more about strong parameters and white listing in [the rails guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

Comment: Thanks for your super fast and accurate response and explanation. It is working now.

Comment: Great! would you mind accepting the answer as correct if the answer solved your issue? Glad I could help!